# How to use HTML for adding new lines in Ionic2 toasts?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2, toast

I try to get some new lines into a toast message.

```
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: "First line<br />Second line.",
        duration: 5000,
        dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    toast.present();
```

But it shows just the tags. How can I get new line (and other HTML tags) into a toast message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rendering HTML tags is not possible here**

There is no way to view HTML tags in toast message as of now due to the way in which toast component's template renders `message` by using [double-curly braces of interpolation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#interpolation)

Reference in IonicFramework Source: [File](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/toast/toast-component.ts#L19) / [Commit](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/bc7d328bc0e2b671ee1a49ffbf3b31a0e9020a6f#diff-a49b0e523ab74f3d8019d3e60fce473eR21)

**Alteratively**, to add new lines in message body for any HTML element

You may use `\x0A` or  `\n` along with `style="white-space: pre-line;"`

**Solution**

```
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: "First line<br />Second line.",
    duration: 5000,
    dismissOnPageChange: true,
    cssClass: "className",
});
toast.present();

.className{
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to show a more complex toast once (with an image and some text), and I did it by using a modal and a few style rules. This is the end result:

[image]

I did it by using Ionic beta by that time, but the code to make it work in RC should be pretty much the same:

```
@Component({
    template:   '<ion-header>' +
                    '<ion-navbar dark>' +
                        '<ion-title>My custom modal</ion-title>' +
                        '<ion-buttons end>' +
                            '<button (click)="dismiss()">Close</button>' +
                        '</ion-buttons>' +
                    '</ion-navbar>' +
                '</ion-header>' +
                '<ion-content padding>' +
                    '<ion-grid>' +
                        '<ion-row>' +
                            '<ion-col width-50><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></ion-col>' +
                            '<ion-col width-50>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</ion-col>' +
                        '</ion-row>' +
                    '</ion-grid>' +
                '</ion-content>',
})
class CustomModalPage {

    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {

    }

    public dismiss() {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Styles:

```
.custom-modal-page {
    height: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 270px);

    ion-content {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #eee;
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed your way, but I am not able to click components on the parent view. (e.g. 'open custom modal' / 'open default modal' button on your example) How could I achieve it?